# How to set a loading page while Django views are loading

Tags: javascript, django

I have a Django app which has a view that pulls data from Bigquery before I render the data to the Frontend. This process of pulling data takes quite some time and it will load the frontend once the view is finished loading the data. Is there a way I could show a loading page while the Django Views are pulling the data then make it disappears once everything is ready?

I tried using the code below:

```js
function onReady(callback) {
     var intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
        if (document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined) {
           window.clearInterval(intervalId);
             callback.call(this);
        }
    }, 1000);
}

function setVisible(selector, visible) {
    document.querySelector(selector).style.display = visible ? 'block' : 'none';
}

onReady(function() {
   setVisible('#app', true);
   setVisible('.loading', false);
});
```

But it seems that it still waits for the data to load, then shows the loading page for 1-2 seconds then immediately loads the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

i am not good in javascript but i face same problem sometimes ago and i use `Wayspoint` for making infinite scroll and this plugging has two event that is very usefull: `onAfterPageLoad` and `onBeforePageLoad`.with these two events you can do what you want `onBeforePageLoad` you can set a spinner (or what ever you want) and `onAfterPageLoad` hide it.
Full documentation is available here: [Full documentation for Wayspoint](http://imakewebthings.com/waypoints/shortcuts/infinite-scroll/)
Best Tutorial: [Best tutorial ever](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/03/13/how-to-create-infinite-scroll-with-django.html)